# Do I need to create a specific privacy policy for my app or can I just use a random one for approval for publishing in the android play store?

Tags: android, android-studio, app-store, google-play-console, privacy-policy

I did not know what to link as my privacy policy page for my app submission for the android play store and so I looked on the internet for answers and apparently I can use any random privacy policy page and my app can still be approved. This is the [page](https://www.privacypolicies.com/blog/mobile-apps-privacy-policy/) that I linked as my privacy policy page, I'm not even sure if its going to get approved so can someone tell me if this is an acceptable privacy policy page or will it get rejected? If it is not then can someone link me something that will work for any type of app.

Comment: Have you discussed your plans with your attorney?

Comment: Google play actually doesnt bother about the privacy policy until it comes to data leak and etc...

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely that Google will approve any apps without a specific Privacy Policy.

To get the app approved:

- Have a descriptive Privacy Policy that discloses your collection and use of images from users
- Complete the Data Safety form to match your Privacy Policy disclosures

If you do not collect any data (including through use of third-party SDKs), simply state so in a Privacy Policy.